# Close OPC-UA connections before create a new one

Tags: qt, opc-ua, qt6

Using the [example](https://doc.qt.io/QtOPCUA/qtopcua-opcuaviewer-example.html) `Qt OPC UA Viewer Example` if I kill the process without disconnecting the client, for some time I cannot connect anymore to the OpcUA server:

```
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Client Status: ChannelState: Open, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: Good"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Selected Endpoint opc.tcp://192.168.1.50:4840 with SecurityMode None and SecurityPolicy http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Selected UserTokenPolicy Anonymous-[0]-None-None with UserTokenType Anonymous and SecurityPolicy http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Received a ServiceFault response"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "The ServiceResult has the StatusCode BadTooManySessions"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Client Status: ChannelState: Open, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: BadTooManySessions"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Client Status: ChannelState: Closed, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: BadTooManySessions"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541: Open62541: Failed to connect
```

As far as I understand this is because the server accept only one connection and if it's not properly closed it does not accept new connections.

Because during development it may happen to kill the process (or it just crashes due to a bug) **is there a way to close the pending connection (if any) *before* attempt a new one?**

I'm running Qt 6.2.0 under Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I imagine there would be a way to configure that session timeout on the server side. Otherwise, you'd have to just restart the server.

Comment: @dtc unfortunately I have no control over the server. I was looking for a client side solution, where I can "tell" the server to disconnect all the pending connections before accepting my new one.

Comment: At this point, speak with the customer or vendor for the OPC UA machine? im not sure :(

Comment: Neither am I, otherwise I would not have asked the question :)